# SharePoint Online full-width page

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, spfx, spfx-webparts, typescript

I am still exploring SharePoint Online creating webparts and deploying through visual studio code using Typescript.

I created a HelloWorld webpart and uploaded it on page. I was able to create package file, upload it on App-Catalog, install it and add to page.

Once it is on page its not taking whole page and in Page Layout section I am not able to see full width option.

As you can see from below screenshot, my webpart is in center of the page whereas What I want is It should be full-width, it should take over whole page.

And in Section layout, full width option is missing.

Can anyone suggest me or give me tip of how to create whole page webpart in SharePoint Online using SPFX.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you are using a Modern Team site, the full width column is currently available only for Communication Site.

To enable your webpart to full-width, you need to set the property `"supportsFullBleed": true,` in your webpart's manifest file. Also, you wont be able to test this webpart locally as full width section is not available on the workbench page.

References - [Use web parts with the full-width column](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/basics/use-web-parts-full-width-column)

[How to add SPFx webpart to full-width column](https://blog.velingeorgiev.com/how-add-spfx-webpart-full-width-column)

Uservoice link - [Full-Width Column Webpart available to Team Site Template](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/32199772-full-width-column-webpart-available-to-team-site-t)

Comment: Thanks @gautam-sheth, That property is set to true. And the screenshot is of page not workbench.

Comment: As mentioned, it is only supported on communication sites, wont work on Modern team sites

Comment: any luck @salah9 ? did you try it on a communication site ?

Comment: I tried adding same web-part to publishing site and it worked.

Comment: @GautamSheth , for out of the box webpart e.g listview -how can we support full width with Teams site? its limitation?

Answer (score 0):

just install modern script editor web part

[image]

then insert CSS:

```
<style type="text/css"> 

#spLeftNav {
    display: none;
}
#spPageCanvasContent {
  margin: auto;
  width: 75%;
} 
    
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to installed the modern script editor web part from here: https://sharepoint.handsontek.net/2023/03/15/use-script-editor-modern-sharepoint-sites/

I then added the script editor TO THE TOP of the page

Then I inspected the html and found this class added to all my webparts: f_a_50a7110f

Then I put the following CSS code intot he Modern Script Editor:

```
<style type="text/css"> 

/* Web Parts */
.f_a_50a7110f{
    max-width: 100%!important;
    
}

/* Header */
.fb_al_9f38462c>.ga_al_9f38462c {
     max-width: 100%!important;
}

</style>
```